# Access runtime 2003 will not start on Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2003, emet

Access runtime 2003 will not start on Windows 10 (Enterprise).

Using an .msi package I can successfully install Access 2003 runtime.

However, when I start Access with Northwind it crashes before displaying the database.
If I start Access without a database it crashes before it reaches the  "You have forgotten your database".

I'm installing on Window 10 enterprise (10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393).
There is only 1 error message in the Application log, error 1000, access violation. (nothing in all the the other logs).
I installed the .msi and enabled verbose logging (18K lines) and there was no evidence of installation problems.

I can repeat the problem on other laptops with the same build.

If I take the .msi and run it on Windows 10 Prof at home I can get Northwind to open as expected.
If I start Access without a database it works, reaches the  "You have forgotten your database" and closes down cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be linked to EMET and DEP.
We have version 5.51 of EMET

By starting the EMET Notification gui (as Admin) and then starting Access I got a notification on the taskbar:

> "EMET detected DEP mitigation and will close the application
>   MSAccess.exe"

This is also logged in the Application log (it was not before).

When I reran sysinternals procmon I could see that EMET had been triggered when MSAccess started to run.

There are options with DEP and within EMET.

However, it turned out that we have DEP protection enabled at all times.
OptOut and OptIn have no effect, Emet still starts.
 and this can only be changed by altering Secure Boot policy

4 values:
bcdedit /set {current} nx AlwaysOn  - our default setting
bcdedit /set {current} nx OptOut  - able to set this but EMET still came on
bcdedit /set {current} nx OptIn - able to set this but EMET still came on
 
bcdedit /set {current} nx AlwaysOff
An error has occurred setting the element data.
The value is protected by Secure Boot policy and cannot be modified or deleted